# traversal through a tree in scheme

Tags: scheme

ok i have this tree:

```
              a6
           /   |  \ 
        a1    a2   p1
                 /    \
              a1       a2
```

and i need some code to traverse it.
in a deep-list represantation it's like this right?
(a1 a2 (a1 a2))?
i already got a method that returns the childerns nodes.
for example if i call it,
(function tree a6) = (a1 a2 p1)
any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little shady on what exactly you are asking, but I will try to get you started.

The deep-list representations of the tree structure you mentioned should look something like this:

```
 '(a6 (a1) (a2) (p1 (a1) (a2)))
```

About a year ago I wrote a few blog articles that you may find useful. [Trees in Scheme: Representation](http://www.andrewbuntine.com/articles/2010/1/24/trees-in-scheme-representation) and [Trees in Scheme: Parsing](http://www.andrewbuntine.com/articles/2010/1/29/trees-in-scheme-parsing).

In the "Parsing" article, I demonstrate the use of mutual recursion (a recursive technique in which two procedures are defined in terms of each other) to effectively parse trees. This should be helpful.

Finally, I also recommend you read chapter 18 of [Simply Scheme](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~bh/ss-toc2.html) for a somewhat thorough introduction to this topic.

Good luck.